# Will GoDaddy's domain forwarding affect subdomains?

Tags: 301-redirect, godaddy, domain-forwarding

I have an old domain registered with GoDaddy.  Let's say it's `olddomain.com`.  I want `olddomain.com` and `www.olddomain.com` to go to `www.newdomain.com`.  The complication is that I have a few subdomains setup using GoDaddy's DNS manager and A records that I do not want affected.

If I use the settings below, will it affect the subdomains?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had another domain which only had one subdomain on it, so I used it as a test.  Setting up the redirect *did not* affect my existing subdomains (A records).

Update: checking the "Update my nameservers and DNS settings to support this change." box *deletes* the `www` CNAME entry which means that only `http://olddomain.com` will forward/redirect.  `http://www.olddomain.com` results in a DNS error!

Our CEO had a link to `www.olddomain.com` in his email signature.  Luckily I clicked on it today to test it after forwarding all our domains. I had to add CNAME entries back to every domain.

Comment: Because www.domain.com is not the same thing as domain.com

Comment: I understand that, I was just a little concerned about exactly how GoDaddy implemented this feature, especially with the "forwarding" terminology (vs Redirect) and the "update DNS..." checkbox.  I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: I found some fallout from using this, which is exactly what I was afraid of.  Updated the answer.